# Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Below is the "singleCard" component code 
if i don't pass in h1 and arcticles I get data, but when I pass {{card.title}} and {{card.body}} - not displayed on page and I get error:

```
**Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"
found in
---> <SingleCard> at src/components/singleCard.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>**
```

```js
<template>
    <div id="single-card">
        <h1>{{ card.title }}</h1>
        <article>{{ card.body }}</article>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                id: this.$route.params.id,
                card: {}
            }
        },
        created() {
            axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + this.id).then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                this.card = response.body;
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: if you initialize `card` with an empty title and body the error should also go away

Answer (score 1):

I think that the data it's not loaded yet, please try this:

```
<div v-if="card" id="single-card">
    <h1>{{ card.title }}</h1>
    <article>{{ card.body }}</article>
</div>
```

Comment: It works if I also I change `response.body` to `response.data` in `created` function. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, if the answer helped you, please vote for useful.

Answer (score 1):

Change `response.body` -> `response.data`

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                id: this.$route.params.id,
                card: {}
            }
        },
        created() {
            axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + this.id).then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                this.card = response.data;
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```